# How to prepare dataset for segformer?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to train a segformer for some medical images and therefore following the Fine tuning tutorial as close as possible [lnk](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-segformer).

The dataset consists of some FMRI images and the specific lesion to segment out, these images are of the same size of the original FMRIs

```
dataset = Dataset.from_dict({"image": img, 'label': mask}).cast_column("image", Image()).cast_column("label", Image())
dataset[0]
{'image': <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=562x471>,
 'label': <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=1 size=562x471>}
```

I've tried to use get_semantic_bitmap from segments-ai.utils with this function

```
def convert_segmentation_bitmap(example):
    return {
        "label.segmentation_bitmap":
            get_semantic_bitmap(
                example["image"],
                example["label"],
                id_increment=0,
            )
    }
```

But this throws a TypeError Exception since PNG are not iterable

What am I missing to obtain the semantic map of this images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your ground truth semantic segmentation map should be a 2D array, that contains a label for each pixel. This means that if you would convert your "label" feature (which is of type Image) to a NumPy array, you obtain a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(dataset[0]['label'])
```

This could look like the following:

```
[[1, 2], [2,2]]
```

Here we have four pixels, three of them being annotated with label 2 and one being annotated with label 1.